# Question about taking an exam in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, advice, learning

When I attend to lectures I can gasp the ideas very quickly. When lecturer explaining something I can even think what is he going to teach next. Actually, in the class, I am faster than the student who gets the highest grades for exams.

But the problem is when I am facing exams I always get low grades and it is hard to face the exams.

Can someone give me any advice to overcome this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take practice exams and time yourself! You can easily find sample papers online. Only when you time yourself you can correctly assess how fast you really are.

Comment: Look up Dunning-Kruger effect.

Answer (score 3):

There are two factors I see a lot that might be at play here.

First, it might be that you're having trouble with problem-solving -- that is, you can do all the steps when the instructor is walking through them, but deciding which steps to take on your own is hard. If that's the case, I recommend practicing more with problems; for example, try solving homework problems without making use of any notes that you won't have access to on the exam. Or, if you've finished the homework, try changing the problems you were given slightly (change a 5 to a 7, for example) and solving them again.

The second possibility is testing anxiety - some students find that just taking a test makes them nervous, and being nervous makes it hard to do math. If that seems like it describes you, I have two recommendations. First, when you study, try to simulate a testing environment for yourself - for example, do practice problems on a timer, while sitting at a desk. Second, you may want to talk to a counselor (many schools have counseling centers available to students) about general strategies for controlling anxiety.

Answer (score 1):

You don't practice enough. You need to take the problem,

which you think that you know perfect and  try to write a full solution.

I am sure that you'll see troubles.

Good luck!